# How do I select columns of a dataframe with character values in R based on the values of the column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that contains three values: `0`, `1`, and `?`. The `0` and `1` values are character values and not numeric. I want to subset the dataframe so as to exclude all the columns with all `0` values. So in the example dataframe below, I want to create a new dataframe with columns `x2` through `x5`. How do I do this in R when the values are characters and not numeric?

```
#   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
# 1  0  0  1 1  1
# 2  0  ?  1 0  1
# 3  0  0  1 0  1
# 4  0  ?  1 1  0
# 5  0  0  1 ?  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `select` columns `where` not `all` values are equal to 0 like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(where(~!all(. == "0")))
#>   x2 x3 x4 x5
#> 1  0  1  1  1
#> 2  ?  1  0  1
#> 3  0  1  0  1
#> 4  ?  1  1  0
#> 5  0  1  ?  1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>